# How to grep for multiple word occurrences from multiple files and list them grouped as rows and columns

Tags: bash, unix, awk

Hello: Need your help to count word occurrences from multiple files and output them as row and columns. I searched the site for a similar reference but could not locate, hence posting it here.

**Setup:**
I have 2 files with the following

```
[a.log]
id,status
1,new
2,old
3,old
4,old
5,old

[b.log]
id,status
1,new
2,old
3,new
4,old
5,new
```

**Results required**
The result i require using the **command line** only is (preferably):

```
file     count(new)    count(old)
a.log    1             4
b.log    3             2
```

**Script**
The script below provides me the count for a single word across multiple.
I am stuck trying to get results for multiple words. Please help.

```
grep -cw "old" *.log
```

Comment: So, `[a.log]` is a different file than `[b.log]` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get this output using `gnu-awk` that accepts comma separated word to be searched in a command line argument:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -F, -v wrds='new,old' 'BEGIN{n=split(wrds, a, /,/); for(i=1; i<=n; i++) b[a[i]]=a[i]} FNR==1{next} $2 in b{freq[FILENAME][$2]++} END{printf "%s", "file" OFS; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "count(%s)%s", a[i], (i==n?ORS:OFS); for(f in freq) {printf "%s", f OFS; for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", freq[f][a[i]], (i==n?ORS:OFS)}}' a.log b.log | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
file   count(new)  count(old)
a.log  1           4
b.log  3           2
```

PS: `column -t` was only used for formatting the output in tabular format.

Readable `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' -F, -v wrds='new,old' 'BEGIN {
   n = split(wrds, a, /,/) # split input words list by comma with int index
   for(i=1; i<=n; i++)     # store words in another array with key as words
      b[a[i]]=a[i]
}
FNR==1 { 
   next # skip first row from all the files
}
$2 in b {
   freq[FILENAME][$2]++ # store filename and word frequency in 2-dimesional array
}
END { # print formatted result
   printf "%s", "file" OFS
   for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
      printf "count(%s)%s", a[i], (i==n?ORS:OFS)

   for(f in freq) {
      printf "%s", f OFS
      for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
         printf "%s%s", freq[f][a[i]], (i==n?ORS:OFS)
   }
}' a.log b.log
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you're looking for something like this, but it's not overly clear what your objectives are (if you're going for efficiency for example, this isn't overly efficient)...

```
for file in *.log; do
    echo -n "${file}\t"
    for word in "new" "old"; do
        grep -cw $word $file;
        echo -n "\t";
    done
    echo;
done
```

(for readability, I simplified the first line, but this  doesn't work if there's spaces in the filenames -- the proper solution is to change the first line to read `find . -iname "*.log" -maxdepth=1 | while read file; do`)

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ 
         FS=","; OFS="\t"; print "file","count(new)","count(old)";
         f1=ARGV[1]; f2=ARGV[2]     # get filenames
     }
     FNR==1{ next }                 # skip the 1st header line
     NR==FNR{ c1[$2]++; next }      # accumulate occurrences of the 2nd field in 1st file
     { c2[$2]++ }                   # accumulate occurrences of the 2nd field in 2nd file
     END{ 
         print f1, c1["new"], c1["old"];
         print f2, c2["new"], c2["old"] 
     }' a.log b.log
```

The output:

```
file    count(new)  count(old)
a.log   1   4
b.log   3   2
```

Comment: Note that OP wrote `to count word occurrences from multiple files` which may mean more than 2 files

Comment: @anubhava, Note this "*I have **2** files with the following*" + I've presented result as **Results required**

Comment: `NR==1 || FNR==1`  is equivalent to  `FNR==1`

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in a b ; do egrep -o "new|old" $c.log | sort | uniq -c > $c.luc; done
```

Get rid of the headlines with grep, then sort and count.

```
join -1 2 -2 2 a.luc b.luc
> new 1 3
> old 4 2
```

Placing a new header is left as an exercise for the reader. Is there a flip command for unix/linux/bash to flip a table, or how would you say?

Handling empty cells is left as an exercise too, but possible with join.

Comment: flipping a table is called `transpose`

Answer (score 0):

without real multi-dim array support, this will count all values in field 2, not just "new/old".  The header and number of columns are dynamic with number of distinct values as well.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 {fs["file"]} 
           FNR>1 {c[FILENAME,$2]++; fs[FILENAME]; ks[$2];
                  c["file",$2]="count("$2")"} 
           END   {for(f in fs) 
                    {printf "%s", f; 
                     for(k in ks) printf "%s", OFS c[f,k]; 
                     printf "\n"}}' file{1,2} | column -t


file   count(new)  count(old)
file1  1           4
file2  3           2
```